# Why won't CreateProcess work in assembly in Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, mingw

I have a C program here that invokes CreateProcess...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  STARTUPINFO st;
  ZeroMemory(%st, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
  st.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  CreateProcessA("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,&st,&pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Which runs fine, creating a shell within a shell.

I also have this code, written in GAS assembly via the MinGW compiler suite for Windows...

```
.extern _CreateProcessA@40
.def    _CreateProcessA@40; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef
.extern _ExitProcess@4
.def    _ExitProcess@4; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef

.text
.globl _main
.def   _main; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef

_main:
      push %ebp
      movl %esp, %ebp

      #PROCESS_INFORMATION...
      subl $16, %esp
      movl %esp, %eax

      #STARTUPINFO...
      subl $68, %esp
      movl $68, (%esp)
      movl %esp, %ebx

      #Application name with path : C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe...
      subl $29, %esp
      xor %edx, %edx
      movb %dx,         27(%esp)
      movb $0x65,       26(%esp)
      movw $0x7856,     24(%esp)
      movl $0x2e646d63, 20(%esp)
      movl $0x5c32336d, 16(%esp)
      movl $0x65747379, 12(%esp)
      movl $0x735c5357, 8(%esp)
      movl $0x4f444e49, 4(%esp)
      movl $0x575c3a43, (%esp)
      movl %esp, %ecx

      push %eax
      push %ebx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %edx
      push %ecx
      call _CreateProcessA@40

      movl %ebp, %esp
      pop  %ebp

      push %edx
      call _ExitProcess@4
```

It compiles and links fine with;

```
as createProc.s -o createProc.o
ld createProc.o -o createProc.exe -lkernel32
```

When it runs though, and it does run, it executes without starting a second shell within a shell on the command line. What could be wrong?

Note : I'm inputting the string with the movl instructions for a reason, so please no suggestions saying that I should be using .data, .bss, or lables. Also note I have already tried using escaped slashes (\\) within the string in the assembly program to no avail, it actually crashes if escaped slashes are used.

Comment: Your code doesn't even assemble. Are you sure you were able to run it?

Comment: Cmd.exe is the command interpreter. Explorer.exe is the shell. Please fix your terminology.

Comment: There may have been a typo, but the code runs perfectly on my end, it just does not create a new process from cmd.exe. And dear IInspectable; if you run my C program you will see that it creates a second shell within a shell, Explorer.exe is the GUI.

Comment: The most obvious difference is that the C code zeros the `STARTUPINFO` structure and, unless I'm missing something, the assembler code doesn't.  If that doesn't fix the problem (or even if it does!) you should add error checking - check the return value from CreateProcess, and if it is zero, call GetLastError and return the result to the user.  (If you don't already have a mechanism for that, the simplest way is to make it your application's exit code.)

Comment: Please read my comment again. I never claimed, that your code should launch a GUI process. It's about terminology, and in Windows, cmd.exe is called "command processor", not "shell", as you insist. Fix your terminology please, as well as the misleading tags.

Comment: See also, e.g., [Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Command-line reference A-Z](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: These are all wonderful tips, but no one is answering why the presented assembly code does not run cmd.exe like it's supposed to.

Comment: Another update, all I'm hearing is people giving advice on programming, no one has helped me figure out why the CreateProcess does not run cmd.exe. I've tried lpApplicationName, and lpCommandLine to no avail. Guys please stop complaining and try to help please, I'm working on this as we speak.

Comment: @August: have you fixed the problem I pointed out yet?  Saying that you have to zero-initialize the `STARTUPINFO` structure isn't just "advice on programming", if you don't do it, CreateProcess() won't work.  (In fact, that's one of the most common reasons for failed CreateProcess() calls.  So it seems very likely to be your problem.)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point in trying to help further you as you haven't posted your actual code the reproduces the problem and you've ignored the help you've already been given.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'll try zeroing out the STARTUPINFO structure. RossRidge The code that reproduces the problem is plain to see above you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HarryJohnson figured it out, all that was needed was to zero out the STARTUPINFO structure,

```
.extern _CreateProcessA@40
.def    _CreateProcessA@40; .scl 2; type 32; .endef
.extern _ExitProcess@4
.def    _ExitProcess@4; .scl 2; type 32; .endef

.text
.globl  _main
.def    _main; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef

_main:
       push %ebp
       movl %ebp, %esp

       xor %edx, %edx

       #PROCESS_INFORMATION...
       subl $16, %esp
       movl %esp, %eax

       #STARTUPINFO...
       subl $68, %esp
       movl %edx, 64(%esp)
       movl %edx, 60(%esp)
       movl %edx, 56(%esp)
       movl %edx, 52(%esp)
       movl %edx, 48(%esp)
       movl %edx, 44(%esp)
       movl %edx, 40(%esp)
       movl %edx, 36(%esp)
       movl %edx, 32(%esp)
       movl %edx, 28(%esp)
       movl %edx, 24(%esp)
       movl %edx, 20(%esp)
       movl %edx, 16(%esp)
       movl %edx, 12(%esp)
       movl %edx, 8(%esp)
       movl %edx, 4(%esp)
       movl %edx, (%esp)
       movb $68, (%esp)
       movl %esp, %ebx

       #Application name (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe)...
       subl $28, %esp
       movb %dl, 27(%esp)
       movb $0x65, 26(%esp)
       movw $0x7865, 24(%esp)
       movl $0x2e646d63, 20(%esp)
       movl $0x5c32336d, 16(%esp)
       movl $0x65747379, 12(%esp)
       movl $0x735c5357, 8(%esp)
       movl $0x4f444e49, 4(%esp)
       movl $0x575c3a43, (%esp)
       movl %esp, %ecx

       push %eax
       push %ebx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %edx
       push %ecx
       call _CreateProcessA@40

       mov %ebp, %esp
       pop %ebp

       push %edx
       call _ExitProcess@4
```

Answer (score 2):

**About programming style**
You should forget about mucking around with `ESP`.
The way to do it is to set up a stack frame at the start of your routine and use `EBP` to address the space thus created.

**You have a typo in your path**
You pass `"c1\win...."` as the path. That's not going to work.
You should double check the code against the [ascii-table](http://www.asciitable.com/), or review the parameters in a debugger making the API call..
Also I have no idea why you need 29 bytes to store the string. It fits in 28 chars as far as I can tell.

**Working code using a stack frame**
Here's code that works using a stack frame the way it is supposed to be done.

```
//Set up stack frame.
00418200 55               push ebp
00418201 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
00418203 83C490           add esp,-$70
//Zero StartupInfoA
00418206 57               push edi
00418207 8D45A0           lea eax,[ebp-$60]
0041820A 8BF8             mov edi,eax
0041820C 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041820E B911000000       mov ecx,$00000011
00418213 F3AB             rep stosd 
//st.cb = SizeOf(st)
00418215 C745A044000000   mov [ebp-$60],$00000044
//Set the string: path = 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe'; 28 chars including trailing 0.
0041821C C745E4433A5C77   mov [ebp-$1c],$775c3a43  //c:\w
00418223 C745E8696E646F   mov [ebp-$18],$6f646e69  //indo
0041822A C745EC77735C73   mov [ebp-$14],$735c7377  //ws\s
00418231 C745F079737465   mov [ebp-$10],$65747379  //yste
00418238 C745F46D33325C   mov [ebp-$0c],$5c32336d  //m32\
0041823F C745F8636D642E   mov [ebp-$08],$2e646d63  //cmd.
00418246 C745FC65786500   mov [ebp-$04],$00657865  //exe- 
//Set up parameters for call
0041824D 8D4590           lea eax,[ebp-$70]        //ProcessInfo
00418250 50               push eax                 
00418251 8D45A0           lea eax,[ebp-$60]        //StartupInfoA
00418254 50               push eax
00418255 6A00             push $00
00418257 6A00             push $00
00418259 6A00             push $00
0041825B 6A00             push $00
0041825D 6A00             push $00
0041825F 6A00             push $00
00418261 6A00             push $00
00418263 8D45E4           lea eax,[ebp-$1c]      //Path
00418266 50               push eax
//Call 
00418267 E80823FFFF       call CreateProcessA
//Clean up the stackframe
0041826C 5F               pop edi
0041826D 8BE5             mov esp,ebp
0041826F 5D               pop ebp
```

**About messing with ESP**
If you set ESP to an unaligned address it will seriously degrade performance.

Comment: "Mucking around" with ESP is how I learned to program in assembly, and I've written many assembly programs with that programming style. I know it works. Thank you for your answer, but you still haven't answered the question why my assembly code runs but does not execute cmd.exe.

Comment: @August: `You pass "c1\win...." as the path.` Messing with ESP is sure to slow down your program to a crawl. It messes with the stack-engine in the CPU; and it needlessly complicates your code as if assembly is not complicated enough already.

Comment: Sorry the the 31 was a typo, it should be 3a... Fixed. I added a call to _ExitProcess@4 at the end, made it stop dying. Still no execution of cmd.exe...

Comment: Once again, I am delighted that you are sharing your expertise in terminology and format, but no one has figured out why my program isn't working, or is trying to for that matter.

Comment: The gcc default (on x86 Linux) is `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  It's fine to use ESP directly, freeing up EBP for use as something other than a frame pointer, as long as you don't break stack unwinding for exceptions.  The only performance issue is that using ESP directly after push/pop/call/ret may require an extra stack-sync uop to be inserted by the stack engine (Intel CPUs only).  ESP-relative addresses unfortunately always need a SIB byte, so code-size suffers slightly.  Making a stack frame sometimes isn't a slowdown, esp in 64-bit code where you're not so register-starved.